# How to change style in MenuItem from PrimeNG

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm trying to change the color of a MenuItem, using PrimeNG here.
Here's my code so far:

```
<p-menu [style]="{'width': '400px'}" #menuOpcoesLista popup="popup" [model]="opcoesListaCS" appendTo="body"></p-menu>
```

And here's my function to create the itens from menu:

```
     this.opcoesListaCS = [
        {label: 'Approve', command: (event) => { this.approve() }},
        {label: 'Send email', command: (event) => { this.sendMail() }},
        {label: 'Details', command: (event) => { this.details() }}];
```

I tried to add style tag, according to PrimeNG docs, but it just doesn´t work. Tried all formats and kinds, tried also class. But non worked for me.

Does anyone know how to change the color? I'd like the first one to be green, second as yellow and third as red.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `styleClass="menucus"`

[image]

**Template code:**

```
<h3>Popup</h3>
<p-menu #menu popup="popup" styleClass="menucus" [model]="items"></p-menu>
<button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-list" label="Show" (click)="menu.toggle($event)"></button>
```

**component code:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuModule, MenuItem } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular 4';
   items: MenuItem[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [{label: 'Approve', command: (event) => { this.approve() }},
        {label: 'Send email', command: (event) => { this.sendMail() }},
        {label: 'Details', command: (event) => { this.details() }}];
    }
    approve() {

    }
    sendMail() {

    }
    details() {

    }
}
```

**CSS code:**

```
/deep/ .menucus ul li:nth-child(1) {
    background: green;
}
/deep/ .menucus ul li:nth-child(2) {
    background: yellow;
}
/deep/ .menucus ul li:nth-child(3) {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks..but didn´t work yet...

I´m using .scss file here..and it complains about the /deep/ part...

Comment: have you try with `::ng-deep` instead of  `/deep/` ?

Comment: What .scss complain ?

Comment: make sure CSS class name are proper. You can inspect css thing in chrome and debug it. i hope it will work.

Comment: try to add css code in component scss file instead of main app scss !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152064/discussion-between-yatin-patel-and-rafael-barioni).